# Converting a RAID 1 drive to a regular one and booting off of it

Tags: raid, software-raid, clone

I'm using `mdadm` to manage a [RAID 1 array with three disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jFe5.png). Would it be possible to take a single drive from the array (i.e. `/dev/sdc`), turning it into a regular drive, and then booting another PC off of that one drive?

I also noticed that `mdadm` didn't make a partition on `/dev/sdc` first (like `/dev/sdc1`) before setting it up as `/dev/sdc/md0` instead of `/dev/sdc/sdc1/md0` like the other disks that are a part of the array. Does this affect me in any way?

Thank you.

[Current disk setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB45g.png)

Comment: Side note: Please don't take screenshots of text. Just copy and paste the text into the question.